# convert NSArray into NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I am new to iOS. I have a warning message and I can t solve it:)
I have the following code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorFirst = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"test" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorFirst,nil];
NSArray *sortedArray =[sections sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

At line 2 I have a warning:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing NSSortDescriptor with an expression of NSArray
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already create NSSortDescriptor in 1st line, so you don't need 2nd one:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorFirst = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"test" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray =[sections sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptorFirst]];
```